# Hide Text From Printing

Tags: html, printing

I have a print page here:

http://www.souq4cars.com/ppreview.php?id=611111161&u=10064&t=users_cars

How do i hide the links at the bottom saying 'Close Window' and 'Print Page' from being printed on the printed page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [CSS @media rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html) for this. To start, add a class `noprint` to the both elements:

```
<a class="noprint">foo</a>
```

and then add a `@media print` rule to your CSS which hides the elements during print:

```
@media print {
    .noprint {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@media print
{
  div.for_hide {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

or you can include some css with this by including

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="/css/print_version.css">
```

in your html code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a new style sheet which uses different css.

```
<link href="style-print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"  type="text/css">
```

Name divs, where you have text, that you don't want to print:

```
<div style="float: right;" id="print">
                <a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.print(); return false;" class="orange_text"><strong>Print Page</strong></a>

            </div>
```

In style-print.css set this divs to hidden.

```
#print {
    display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a print stylesheet and hide the relevant elements there by setting `display: none`.

You can include a print sheet by adding the following between the head tags:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />`
Normally you would set the `media` attribute to `screen` or something similar.