# Preventing print icon getting printed

Tags: html, jquery-ui

How to prevent print icon getting printed HTML

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790049/hide-text-from-printing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the @media CSS selector. Simplified example:

```
<style rel="stylesheet" href="somestyle.css" />
<img src="/some/file.png" class="print_me_not" />
```

in somestyle.css:

```
@media print {
  .print_me_not {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

inside your head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

in print.css:

```
a#print-icon { visibility: hidden; }
```

(I don't know the actual selector as you didn't post your HTML. Please post your code in future questions. Have fun!)

Comment: +1 - Just to note, in cases where just one little property like this is needed, you can also use a `<style>` tag directly.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Possibly, yes, but it's kind of messy. IRL, it's never "one little property" in the end, and this syntax makes it easy to separate print styles from the rest. (+1, wasn't aware of the `media=` option)

Comment: @Piskvor - Often it can be, `.noprint` :)

Comment: @Nick that is too much bandwidth for non-iOS mobile devices as they cannot print anyway. You know, `class="noprint"` is 15 bytes for every element that cannot be printed anyway!

Comment: @Nick Craver: Good point. OTOH, printed media benefits from different layout/font selection/feature selection (remove ads? remove "this is hot now" or other side-features?) than a web page - in my experience, there are things you don't want to straight-out omit in the printed version, but you may want to present them differently.

Answer (score 1):

another method:
  in your main css file:

```
@media print {
    #printerIcon { display: none; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSS Media Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html).

**Example:**

```
<style type="text/css">
 @media print { 
  #yourPrintIcon { display: none; }
 }
</style>
```