# Print Visible DIV Only

Tags: html, css

I have created many div/blocks in a html page which is able to show the blocks chosen and hide the blocks not chosen.

But when printing, it could not print only those blocks that are chosen. it will print all the chosen and also all the hidden blocks.

What can I do to ONLY print those blocks user chosen to be printed and not printing those hidden blocks??

Comment: Take a look here - http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/

Comment: Hidden blocks are hidden using `display: none`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in your style sheet. Assuming the hidden blocks have a class of hidden, and chosen have a class of chosen.

```
@media print
{

  div,.hidden{display:none;}
  .chosen{display:block;}
}
```

Google print style sheets for more information.
See: [Hide Text From Printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790049/hide-text-from-printing)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a media query that targets just the print view to generically create a print stylesheet:

```
@media print {
      .class-i-want-to-show {
          width: 100%;
      }

      .class-i-want-to-hide {
          display: none;
      }
}
```

To dynamically hide elements in the print view, you could just look at all the divs that get some no-print class applied to them by another function and tell them to display: none; on your print page.

```
$( "div" ).parent( ".dont-print-me" ).css( "display", "none" );
```

I'd have to know a little more about what you are really trying to do to recommend a more comprehensive script.

Comment: hi, thanks. do i just need to add this code to html or css? or need to add other coding as well ?

Comment: and it is possible because we dont know which one user is going to select and which one is not.. how to add/write the coding?

Comment: If you want to target individual classes, you will need to inject CSS styles dynamically via something like jquery.